# Executar código na linguagem Lua

Tags: lua

Baixei o interpretador da linguagem Lua, criei um arquivo `hello.lua` com o código abaixo:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Mas não consigo compilar esse código e exibir a saída. Baixei a versão 5.3.3 e executei o arquivo `lua.exe`, o console é exibido e digitei: `lua hello.lua`, mas o erro abaixo é apresentado:

[image: interpretador Lua]

Detalhe, a execução do código direto no console funciona, ou seja, se eu digitar print("hello world") o retorno é `hello world`. Mas o que quero é executar através de um arquivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer:

```
dofile("hello.lua")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ExecuteScript.lua).

Ou pode sair do interpretador e rodar direto

```
lua hello.lua
```

Comment: Funcionou com o dofile. Mas tentei fora do interpretador e não consegui. Qual o instalador correto para que o comando seja reconhecido?

Comment: Não existe instalador correto, se você tem tudo aí é para funcionar, mas isso é outro problema. Veja: https://www.lua.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Caso aconteça com alguém futuramente, é só colocar a versão após o comando lua.

A versão postada é *5.3.3*, então o correto seria colocar `lua53`

Exemplo:

```
lua53 hello.lua
```